# ImportError: No module named gtk

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, gtk

I have a PC running Ubuntu 17.10. I want to runn a python script that uses gtk. HoweverI get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/selectvm.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

I have tried already many things like:

```
sudo apt install python-gtk2 
sudo apt install python-gtk2-dev
```

but none of them works. APT says they are already installed.

Comment: Those packages are for Python 2.x, are you by chance trying to import from Python 3.x?

Comment: @JacobWood I entered to python console and tried to import gtk and it says I'm using python2.7

Comment: (In console) try: `pip install PyGTK`

Comment: @JacobWood I get: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xPKnXX/PyGTK/

Comment: If you wrote this script, convert to Gtk3. If somebody else wrote it, get them to migrate or migrate the script to Gtk3 yourself. You will thank yourself in the end. Gtk2 is getting near end of life.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2
```

> These are the python bindings for GTK.

Graphic package nessesary to build the software-center UI.

Or:

```
sudo apt-get install afnix
```

[credits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49782/importerror-no-module-named-gtk)

Comment: `Error: Unable to find a match: python-gtk2`

Comment: PyGTK is only available for Python 2.6 on Windows.

For more fresh installation instructions see https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install it on 20.04 from the downloaded python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb file. Not from apt repository.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).